# Regarding NOSQL - Alternatives to RDBMS

Tags: nosql

I have been stumbled on things like RDBMS alternatives very often now a days... And i am following some of the open source implementation..

What I understand is: it is best suited for the web apps in large scale (like google & amazon).. they mainly concentrated on very large distributed data stores..

how this could help small start ups looking for a existing costly alternative data stores.. and is this really yield both performance & maintanance gain for small applications?

I just started this discussion and belive somebody here already got same frustration trying these new approaches earlier and may gain experience in it.. this may help start ups like us..

Comment: Hi, This post is from 09 i think now have better experience and knowledge about the question you asked and there is lots of new technology, can you please share your thought and experience about this question?

Comment: Thats a good idea @souvickcse, i would definitely do that soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on your scaling requirments. RBDMS require locks to work and so can only really be scaled "up". NoSQL-style DBs such as Googles bigtable and CouchDB are massively scalable and very cheap, but can get very complicated to write an app on top of as developers have to deal with all kinds of data consistency/fault tolerance issues in thier application layer.

I would say for a small application you're probably better off with a SQL-based relational database. Whilst in theory much more expensive, being realistic at a small scale that price trades off as a much simpler system to work with.

If however you're start up is a muti-tenant solution which needs to deal with a lot of writes, I'd look carefully at alternatives.

Comment: SQL + cache(NoSQL) is usually better than trying to fit everything in column or document storage.